# Mapbox scripts are being blocked by ad-blockers/extensions

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl, mapbox-api-directions, mapbox-api-geocoding

I am using Mapbox API in my webapp and it seems like, some ad-blockers or extensions are blocking my mapbox scripts, resulting the bugs in displaying the map on the app. If I go into the incognito tab, the app works fine. If I switch the browser, the app works fine too. How can I cope with this situation?

[image]